How to achieve a top-to-bottom FlowLayoutPanel where invisible items don't take up space
I have forms in my application that are variable length based on configuration in a database. These currently use TableLayoutPanels, and basically have a question followed by an answer like the below example:

There is logic to make fields invisible or visible based on the data in other fields. Currently it sets the height of a row to zero and makes the control invisible when it is not to display.
This causes issues with scrolling using a TableLayoutPanel (it doesn't calculate height correctly and cuts fields off the page), so I am trying to change this to a FlowLayoutPanel, which seems more appropriate for this sort of thing anyway. However, this now causes the problem that invisible items take up space.
My problems are:

Even when I set the height, width, padding and margin of controls in the FlowLayoutPanel to 0 as part of the invisible logic, they take up space in the FlowLayoutPanel
Then when I try and set the Label control back to Autosize when an item is made visible again, it stays as width 0 and height 0 (the dropdowns/text entry fields on the other hand come back fine).

I have tried calling a Refresh() on controls after they are changed too and that doesn't help either.
Is there a way I can achieve what I need with a FlowLayoutPanel or is there something else I should use?
Here is the code that makes items invisible vs visible, noting that I've tried several different things for the margins
  if(finalExpressionValue.Equals("1"))
  {
      lblToHide.Visible = true;
      lblToHide.AutoSize = true;
      lblToHide.Margin = new Padding(3);

      lblToHide.Padding = new Padding(3);
  }
  else
  {
      lblToHide.Visible = false;
      lblToHide.AutoSize = false;
   /*   lblToHide.Height = 0;
      lblToHide.Width = 0;*/
      lblToHide.Margin = new Padding(0);
      lblToHide.Padding = new Padding(0);
  }
  lblToHide.Refresh();


Can you insert the designer and form codes (a minimal)?

Hey @ShahramAlemzadeh, none of the creation of the FlowLayoutPanel takes place in the Designer as it is all code driven. I will insert the code that creates it into the question.

The default label padding is zero for all sides, so it seems lblToHide.Padding = new Padding(3); is not necessary. Also, the default top and bottom margin is zero and not 3. Try lblToHide.Margin = new Padding(3,0,3,0); for visible state and check the result. And if you are using form scaling, it is better to save the label margin in a global variable before hiding it and restore the label padding from this variable when showing it because form scaling may affect the value of margin.

Hey @ShahramAlemzadeh have given this a crack and unfortunately they still take up space when hidden - any other ideas?

Hi again @Thomas, I was not able to reproduce the problem. I made a very simple demo based on the previous comment and it runs without problem, i.e. revisable items in the panel appear exactly at the same location before hiding (vertically and horizontally). And by the way, the lblToHide.Refresh(); is also not needed. I recommend debugging the program and checking the coordinates just before hiding and before showing and compare them.

@ShahramAlemzadeh I have tried looking at this in the debugger and Width, Height, Padding and Margin are all set as they should be on hide/show in the debugger (i.e. have values of 0 when hidden and the values of 3 when shown). The X/Y coordinates do not change between Hide and Show which is what I'd expect. I have noticed that the size is 0,0 after a hidden control changes to show, but I assume Autosize being True should override that. Any chance of sharing your code so I can have a look at what I might be doing incorrectly?

Sure. I have to post the code as an answer, though it is not a real one. Please let me know when to delete it.

This is a temporary answer just to show sample code trying to reproduce the problem.
The form consists of a flowLayoutPanel containing 8 labels and two buttons to hide/show Label3
Padding xpad;

private void Btn_Hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xpad = label3.Margin;
    label3.Margin = new Padding(0);
    label3.Visible = false;
}

private void Btn_Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label3.Margin = xpad;
    label3.Visible = true;
} 

The designer (if it helps):
   private void InitializeComponent()
   {
       this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
       this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.Btn_Hide = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
       this.Btn_Show = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
       this.SuspendLayout();
       // 
       // flowLayoutPanel1
       // 
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label4);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label5);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label6);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label7);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label8);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(117, 80);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(449, 308);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
       // 
       // label1 to label8
       // 
       this.label1.AutoSize = true;
       this.label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
       this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16.2F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
       this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
       this.label1.Name = "label1";
       this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 34);
       this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
       this.label1.Text = "label1";

       // Btn_Hide
       // Btn_Show

       // 
       // Form78553340
       // 
       this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
       this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
       this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1016, 509);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Btn_Show);
       this.Controls.Add(this.Btn_Hide);
       this.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
       this.Name = "Form78553340";
       this.Text = "Form78553340";
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
       this.flowLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
       this.ResumeLayout(false);

   }


Wow, this example wholly and completely works without even changing the size of the labels. I will try and work out what's gone wrong with my code using this. Thank you
